# Animating HorizontalScrollView in sequence.

Tags: android, animation

So in my android app I have a HorizontalScrollView that will display images. All images are downloaded an added to the View before it is avalible to the user. However when it does apear I want each image to animate in seperatly. Ive tried a LayoutTransition object attached to my layout with this code to show the views:

```
    transition = new LayoutTransition();
    transition.setStagger(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, 500);
    transition.setDuration(1000);
    transition.setAnimateParentHierarchy(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < mGallery.getChildCount(); i++) {
        mGallery.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        transition.showChild(mGallery, mGallery.getChildAt(i));
    }
```

I have also tried this method using the the AnimationEndListener, and a recursive animateView() method

```
    private void animateView(final int index) {
    if (mGallery.getChildAt(index) == null)
        return;
    final View child = mGallery.getChildAt(index);
    final Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mRootView.getContext(), R.anim.slideup);

    AnimationEndListener listener = new AnimationEndListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            animateView(index + 1);
        }
    };

    an.setAnimationListener(listener);
    child.setAnimation(an);
    child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    an.start();
}
```

The first method is preferable however it always animates in all my images at the same time. The second method kind of works, however it will apply the animation to the first view and the all subsequent views will appear in sequence without the animation playing.

Comment: I have done this recursion in my project and it works fine your code seems to be working fine however in first method you need to put it in recursion to achieve this. Try setting duration in second method

Comment: Secondly i would recommend you to use Horizontal LIstview instead of scrollview. Listviews have recycling in them and when items are more you will not face out of memory exception howeven in scrollview you can encounter this when server is returning bunch of data

Comment: Does android have horizantol listViews. I do not see it in the docs anywhere? Nor do I see any way of making the listview horizantol

Comment: Also my second method is recursive. It runs the animation, and then on animation end it calls itself.